# Enum not being added to Realm Class

Tags: ios, swift, enums, realm

I'm trying to add a `Enum` to my Person object however when i open the Realm Browser it does not appear in there and when i try to return it returns nil? Below you will see what i've tried.

**Object**

```
enum Type {
    case Cat(name: String, outDoor: Bool)
    case Dog(name: String, activityLevel: Int)
}

class Person:Object {
    var type: Type?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Realm does not support Swift enums (see the docs section on [supported types](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types) for what is supported). There is no error for them like other unsupported types have because enum properties don't show up in the obj-c runtime's property list at all.